# CSS for menu item added via functions.php

Tags: functions, menus

I have added a current date item successfully to my menu via functions.php (**Wordpress 4.7**)  using:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_todaysdate_in_menu', 10, 2);
function add_todaysdate_in_menu( $items, $args ) {
    if( $args->theme_location == 'header-menu')  {

        $todaysdate = date('l jS F Y');
        $items .=  '<li class="menu-item">' . $todaysdate .  '</li>';

    }
    return $items;
}
```

My problem is, that the styling is different to those item added in the wp-admin backend. I have tried a few things according to [WP Menu Item CSS Classes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/#menu-item-css-classes), but still got problems with the classes. Help would be great. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, menu items are rendered as an `<li>` tag with an `<a>` tag inside. You could simply wrap `$todaysdate` in an anchor so that this item will be styled like the others:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_todaysdate_in_menu', 10, 2);
function add_todaysdate_in_menu( $items, $args ) {
    if( $args->theme_location == 'header-menu')  {

        $todaysdate = date('l jS F Y');
        $items .=  '<li class="menu-item menu-item-date"><a>' . $todaysdate .  '</a></li>';

    }
    return $items;
}
```

To keep the item from showing a hand cursor when hovering, add this CSS:

```
.menu-item-date a:hover {
    cursor: default;
    /* Other styles for hovered date item */
}
```

Alternatively, you could leave out the `<a>` tag wrapper and create styles for `.menu-item-date` to make this item look like the others, but that might be more work.